# Mocking only a single `window` property with Jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs, mocking, window, enzyme

I have a React component that makes a call to `window.location.href`.

As part of my Jest test, I mock the value of `window.location.href` as follows:

```
const mockWindow = { location: { href: 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions' } };
jest.spyOn(window, 'window', 'get').mockImplementation(() => mockWindow);

const wrapper = mount(<MyComponent />);
```

However when I run it, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object

    > |   const wrapper = mount(<MyComponent />);
      |                   ^
```

This tells me there is an internal React issue when rendering/mounting the component. The issue is specifically caused by me mocking the `window` object. When I uncomment that line and re-run it, it doesn't not raise this error.

I'm *guessing* that React internally makes other calls to `window.*` and because I mocked the whole object, those calls made by React return `undefined` and the component does not render.

**How do I mock only a single property of `window` while leaving other properties untouched?**

Alternately, are there any other reasons this would error? Or are there other clever ways to get around this issue?

Comment: I don't understand why you did `jest.spyOn(window, 'window', 'get')`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing jest.spyOn(window, 'window'...) try using (global, 'window'...) like the following:

```
const originalWindow = { ...window };
const windowSpy = jest.spyOn(global, "window", "get");
windowSpy.mockImplementation(() => ({
  ...originalWindow,
  location: {
    ...originalWindow.location,
    href: "http://my.test/page",
    replace: mockedReplace,
  },
}));
```

And after remeber to clean it up:

```
windowSpy.mockRestore();
```

You can check out better following [this example](https://www.grzegorowski.com/how-to-mock-global-window-with-jest)

Comment: `global === window` in Jest DOM environment, so it doesn't add anything to original snippet, and `...window` can break things because it discards some properties.

Comment: @EstusFlask - you are correct. I dug deeper into my error and it's caused by `window.HTMLIFrameElement` beinig `undefined`. The spy approach above is clever, but `{...window}` still does not duplicate the `HTMLIFrameElement` property (whcih is a `function()`), and so the error remains.